# How do I easily support light and dark mode with a custom color used in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, ios-darkmode, uitraitcollection

Let's say I have a custom color in my app:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    static var myControlBackground: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

I use this in a custom control (and other places) as the control's background:

```swift
class MyControl: UIControl {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        backgroundColor = .myControlBackground
    }

    // Lots of code irrelevant to the question
}
```

With iOS 13, I wish to have my custom control support both light and dark mode.

One solution is to override `traitCollectionDidChange` and see if the color has changed and then update my background as needed. I also need to provide both a light and dark color.

So I update my custom colors:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    static var myControlBackgroundLight: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
    }
    static var myControlBackgroundDark: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.3, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

And I update my control code:

```swift
extension MyControl {
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
                backgroundColor = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
                   .myControlBackgroundDark : .myControlBackgroundLight
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work but it's clunky and anywhere else I happen to use `myControlBackground` needs to have the same code added.

Is there a better solution to having my custom color and control support both light and dark mode?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As it turns out, this is really easy with the new `UIColor init(dynamicProvider:)` initializer.

Update the custom color to:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var myControlBackground: UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return UIColor { (traits) -> UIColor in
                // Return one of two colors depending on light or dark mode
                return traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
                    UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.4, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1) :
                    UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
            }
        } else {
            // Same old color used for iOS 12 and earlier
            return UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. No need to define two separate statics. The control class doesn't need any changes from the original code. No need to override `traitCollectionDidChange` or anything else.

The nice thing about this is that you can see the color change in the app switcher immediately after changing the mode in the Settings app. And of course the color is up-to-date automatically when you go back to the app.

On a related note when supporting light and dark mode - Use as many of the provided colors from UIColor as possible. See the available dynamic colors from [UI Elements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_color) and [Standard Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors). And when you need your own app-specific colors to support both light and dark mode, use the code in this answer as an example.

---

In Objective-C, you can define your own dynamic colors with:

UIColor+MyApp.h:

```
@interface UIColor (MyApp)

@property (class, nonatomic, readonly) UIColor *myControlBackgroundColor;

@end
```

UIColor+MyApp.m:

```
+ (UIColor *)myControlBackgroundColor {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        return [UIColor colorWithDynamicProvider:^UIColor * _Nonnull(UITraitCollection * _Nonnull traits) {
            return traits.userInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyleDark ?
                [self colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.4 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0] :
                [self colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.4 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
        }];
    } else {
        return [self colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.4 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you got the right idea!  For completeness, there is one more option: Define a custom color in an asset catalog, then get the color using `UIColor(named:)` / `+[UIColor colorNamed:]`.

Comment: Any ideas why on Xcode 11 Beta 5 I am getting `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` on the UIColor init call?

Comment: Mystery solved - I am using the same swift file in the Apple Watch target itself and it fails on the watch OS

Comment: how would i handle different images, you're using the convinience init provided by the UIColor. i tried to add that locally in extension but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique Please post your own question with all relevant details and code.

Comment: I had to use the link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_colors to get to the UI Elements colors you mentioned (you were just missing the `s` at the end. Maybe they changed the URL).

Answer (score 19):

Another solution with **iOS 13** is to define custom colors in your asset catalog using Xcode’s asset editor.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface), when you need a specific color, create it as a color asset. In your asset, specify different color values for both *light* and *dark* appearances. You can also specify high-contrast versions of your colors.

[image]

Note that **Any Appearance** variant is the color that is displayed on older systems that do not support Dark Mode.

To load a color value from an asset catalog, you can load the color by its name:

```
// iOS
let aColor = UIColor(named: "customControlColor")

// macOS
let aColor = NSColor(named: NSColor.Name("customControlColor"))
```

Now anytime user switches between dark and light mode, the specified colors will dynamically change through the app.

Answer (score 16):

Here I got this helper method to create dynamic colors:

```
extension UIColor {
    static func dynamicColor(light: UIColor, dark: UIColor) -> UIColor {
        guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else { return light }
        return UIColor { $0.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? dark : light }
    }
}
```

And for the solution in the question, the helper method should be used as the following:

```
extension UIColor {
    static let myControlBackground: UIColor = dynamicColor(light: UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1), dark: UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.3, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1))
}
```

No need to override `traitCollectionDidChange`, just set the `backgroundColor` once and you are done.

Comment: Great and convenient solution!

Answer (score 5):

In case you are want to create dynamic colours programmatically:

Reusable extension:

```swift
extension UIColor {

   public class func dynamicColor(light: UIColor, dark: UIColor) -> UIColor {
      if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
         return UIColor {
            switch $0.userInterfaceStyle {
            case .dark:
               return dark
            default:
               return light
            }
         }
      } else {
         return light
      }
   }
}
```

App Colors:

```swift
struct MyColors {

   ///> This is what you are getting from designers,
   /// in case they are not providing consistent color naming.
   /// Can be also just strings with HEX-codes.
   static let xF9EFB1 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882352941, green: 0.9372549019607843, blue: 0.6941176470588235, alpha: 1)
   static let x6A6A6A = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4156862745098039, green: 0.4156862745098039, blue: 0.4156862745098039, alpha: 1)
   static let xFEFEFE = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9960784313725490, green: 0.9960784313725490, blue: 0.9960784313725490, alpha: 1)
   static let x202020 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1254901960784314, green: 0.1254901960784314, blue: 0.1254901960784314, alpha: 1)
   ///<

   static var myLabelForeground: UIColor {
      return UIColor.dynamicColor(light: MyColors.x6A6A6A, dark: MyColors.xF9EFB1)
   }

   static var myViewBackground: UIColor {
      return UIColor.dynamicColor(light: MyColors.xFEFEFE, dark: MyColors.x202020)
   }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
class SampleView: View {

   private lazy var label = Label(text: "Hello!")

   override func setupUI() {
      label.textColor = MyColors.myLabelForeground
      label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold)
      backgroundColor = MyColors.myViewBackground
      addSubview(label)
      LayoutConstraint.centerXY(label).activate()
   }

}
```

Result:

[image: Light]
[image: Dark]

---

**UPDATE**: `NSColor` extension:

```swift
import AppKit

extension NSColor {

   public class func dynamicColor(light: NSColor, dark: NSColor) -> NSColor {
      if #available(OSX 10.15, *) {
         return NSColor(name: nil) {
            switch $0.name {
            case .darkAqua, .vibrantDark, .accessibilityHighContrastDarkAqua, .accessibilityHighContrastVibrantDark:
               return dark
            default:
               return light
            }
         }
      } else {
        return light
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: They won't react to system appearance changes if you create them like that.

Comment: Depends how it's used. If called dynamically in a SwiftUI view, system appearance changes will be picked up.