# How to avoid or prevent dark mode in app?

Tags: themes, ios13, xcode11, ios-darkmode

iPhone device theme is Dark. So my app theme getting some changes because of this. Can i prevent this dark mode in my app? if yes How?

Comment: Yes, you can opt-out of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your info.plist

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

The game is on **Default color**.

In **Light theme Default color is White**.

On the other hand, In **dark theme Default color is Black**.

Now we can make our app's appearance as device's theme.