# Dark Mode AppStore policy

Tags: app-store, ios13, ios-darkmode

Hello I would like to know if forcing my app to light mode by setting `User Interface Style` to `Light` in plist can result to the rejection of my app ??

Answer (score 2):

The [Official Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13) states:

> Supporting Dark Mode is strongly encouraged. Use the UIUserInterfaceStyle key to opt out only temporarily while you work on improvements to your app's Dark Mode support.

So your app will not be rejected (yet) for using this key. Howver, you should start supporting dark mode.

Additional information can be found here: [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)

Comment: I read the documentation and I did not find anything that indicates that the app will be rejected if I use this property. But I found many people who have encountered this problem. 
After some research I think this rejection problem only occurs on xcode V10 and it is no longer occurred on version 11.