# How to force disable iOS dark mode in React Native

Tags: react-native, ios13, ios-darkmode

The new iOS 13 update introduces an optional system-wide.
This causes e.g. the StatusBar to have light text, which might become unreadable on a white background. It also breaks the iOS Datetime Picker (see [DatePickerIOS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26299)
or [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/issues/296))

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The solution is to either

1. add this to your Info.plist file:

```
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
```

OR

2. Add this to your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        rootView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
    }
```

Comment: @Hazwin that sounds unlikely

Comment: @MaximZubarev I guess he is referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546554/827027

Comment: @Hazwin that's not true if you are using an updated version of Xcode and can be very misleading for someone reading the comments. I have more than one app in the app store using UIUserInterfaceStyle ligth in Info.plist

Comment: @Jero yes. my bad. I was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13/56546554#56546554

Answer (score 3):

In your app.json file add:

```
{
  "expo": {
     ...
     "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIUserInterfaceStyle": "Light"
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

1. Add this to Info.plist

> ```
> <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
> <string>Light</string>
> ```

2. And this to your AppDelegate.m

> ```
>   if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
>       rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
>     self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
>   } else {
>       rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work best. Add this in your `AppDelagate.m`

```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  //add this here vv

  if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
     self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
  }

  //add this here ^^




 return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Info.plist

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
```

And this to your AppDelegate.m

```
  rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```