# Why doesn't my iOS app disable dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, ios-darkmode

So ... I've tried to set my app to disable iOS 13 dark mode by forcing light mode according apple documentation, in the emulator all attempts work fine, but when I try on the real device, nothing happens, it's like I've never changed my code

**First Attempt**

*Override the Interface Style for a Window, View, or View Controller*

I tried to put this code sample in my viewDidLoad()

***Nothing Changed***

```swift
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
} else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

**Second Attempt**

*Opt Out of Dark Mode Entirely*

The system automatically opts in any app linked against the iOS 13.0 or later SDK to both light and dark appearances. If you need extra time to work on your app's Dark Mode support, you can temporarily opt out by including the UIUserInterfaceStyle key (with a value of Light) in your app’s Info.plist file. Setting this key to Light causes the system to ignore the user's preference and always apply a light appearance to your app.

***Nothing changed***

[Apple Documentation: Choosing a Specific Interface Style for Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app)

If anyone knows how I set my app only in light mode... I'll be very grateful :D

Comment: Everything you've posted in the question is correct. You have even stated that it works in the simulator. The problem on a real device may be that the app isn't actually being updated. Delete your app from the device then reinstall through Xcode. Does it work now just as it does in the simulator?

Comment: Possible duplicarte of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13/64693329#64693329

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply you can add a new key **`UIUserInterfaceStyle`** in your app **info.plist** (Notes: Xcode 12 and above has renamed to **`Appearance`**) and set its value to **`Light or Dark`**. this will override the app default style to the value you provide.

so you don't need to bother about having it anywhere else

Comment: when I run my app in emulator, this solution work's fine, but in real device, nothing changed

Comment: try uninstalling the app from device first and check if you are using the same info.plist file and also make sure you are cleaning the project

Comment: This answer doesn't actually solve the issue. The OP was already using the Info.plist key. At least redo the answer with the actual solution which was needing to delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: Make sure value is `Light`, not `light` (it's case sensitive)

Comment: this is driving me crazy. I have checked the case of "Light", cleaned the project, deleted it from both the simulator and the real device, but nothing is preventing the app from going into dark mode with dark mode set.

info.plist clearly recognizes the "Appearance" property

Comment: Note that the actual key in the info.plist file is `UIUserInterfaceStyle` (Open As -> Source Code) but displays as `Appearance` (Open As -> Property List)

Answer (score 5):

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

Should work. Call it in your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: But under iOS 13, your app's window won't be in the app delegate, it will be in the scene delegate unless you have completely opted out of scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Change the window UserInterfaceStyle for iOS 13+ version. Just set

```
UIApplication.shared.changeStatusBarStyle(.light)
```

or

```
UIApplication.shared.changeStatusBarStyle(.dark)
```

after changing window every time.

```
extension UIApplication {

        enum StatusColor {

            case dark, light
        }

        func changeStatusBarStyle(_ mode: StatusColor = .light) {

            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

                guard let appDelegate = delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

                var interfaceStyle: UIUserInterfaceStyle

                switch mode {
                case .dark:
                    interfaceStyle = .dark
                default:
                    interfaceStyle = .light
                }

                appDelegate.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = interfaceStyle
            }
        }
    }
```

If any confusion please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Add inside **Info.plist**

```
<key>Appearance</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI you might find the following solution helpful:

```
extension UIApplication {
    func changeInterfaceStyle(_ mode: UIUserInterfaceStyle = .light) {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            var window: UIWindow? {
                guard let scene = connectedScenes.first,
                      let windowSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
                      let window = windowSceneDelegate.window else {
                    return nil
                }
                return window
            }
            window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = mode
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    Button("Dark") {
        UIApplication.shared.changeInterfaceStyle(.dark)
    }
```