# UINavigationController NavigationBar background image not working after updating XCode to 11.4 on Visual Studio Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xcode11.4

I was using this code before, now this is not working. I am using gradient image to add on navigationbar background. This was working before xcode 11.4 update but after updating this has stoped working. Moreover title is also shown in black color. I tried changing color it didn't worked.

```
var img = UIImage.FromBundle("navbar_image").CreateResizableImage(UIEdgeInsets.Zero, UIImageResizingMode.Stretch);
NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(img, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

This is before imgae[image: This is before imgae]

Now it is showing like this with title in black color[image: Now it is showing like this with title in black color]

Comment: Try to use UINavigationBarAppearance to set the title color instead, you can have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848786/xcode-11-4-navigations-title-color-gone-black-from-storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
        {
            UINavigationBarAppearance appearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
            var img = UIImage.FromBundle("navbar_image").CreateResizableImage(UIEdgeInsets.Zero, UIImageResizingMode.Stretch);
            appearance.BackgroundImage = img;
            appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
            appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.CompactAppearance = appearance;
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.StandardAppearance = appearance;
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;

        }
        else
        {
            var img = UIImage.FromBundle("navbar_image").CreateResizableImage(UIEdgeInsets.Zero, UIImageResizingMode.Stretch);
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(img, UIBarMetrics.Default);
            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
        }
```

Comment: You can mark it as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).