# Will apple reject my app if i force light mode on my app?

Tags: ios, ios-darkmode

I know i can force my app to always use light mode from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13). But some say apple will reject the app and some say not. So will apple reject my app if i force my app to use light mode?

Comment: Only Apple can answer that. However, there is nothing in the review guidelines that suggest it will reject your app.
They have even added a special property for that which suggests they want us to use it. Also, some applications just cannot have two modes.

Comment: which xcode you used for uploading the build?

Comment: I have successfully released my app only in light mode. no rejection :D

Answer (score 5):

Please read the docs

> Supporting both light and dark appearances is a good practice, but you
>   might have good reasons to opt out of appearance changes wholly or
>   partially in your app. Views containing user-created content should
>   always reflect the user’s choices. Similarly, you might choose a
>   specific appearance for print-related views so that they reflect what
>   the user sees on the printed page.
>
> The system assumes that apps linked against the iOS 13 or later SDK
>   support both light and dark appearances. In iOS, you specify the
>   specific appearance you want by assigning a specific interface style
>   to your window, view, or view controller. You can also disable support
>   for Dark Mode entirely using an Info.plist key.

It's clearly fine to opt out

The only change about apps linked against iOS 13 is that BY DEFAULT they assume you're fine with dark and light mode.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app

Comment: Just in case anyone won't trust the docs: I can confirm that forcing either light OR dark mode does not result in rejection. I've released apps with both constellations.