# Disable dark mode on specific screens in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

To disable dark mode for the iOS app, we can simply set `UIUserInterfaceStyle` in **Info.plist** to `Light`.

But how do I disable dark mode on specific `UIViewController`'s?

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13

Answer (score 4):

You can force viewController to act as you want. In `viewDidLoad` you have to follow this code to change `UserInterfaceStyle`

**Objective-C**

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    [self setOverrideUserInterfaceStyle: UIUserInterfaceStyleLight];
}
```

**Swift**

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using Titanium classic framework?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable dark mode on specific view controllers than you have to put this code in viewcontroller's viewDidLoad method

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // overrideUserInterfaceStyle is available with iOS 13
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        // Always adopt a light interface style.
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of disabling it, you can use following code to make it look like it is disabled

  ```
  if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
  {
       self.view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
       // This will solve the problem (Current View will never be in dark mode

  }
  ```

Comment: what about labels, buttons, textfields, tableview cells, etc. on screen? they will behave with respect to dark mode.

Comment: You're right !!!, I've edited the answer @Mahendra