# Change between Light and Dark mode for entire app

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-darkmode

I want to have a dark mode option within the settings page of my Xcode swift app. Is it possible to change dark mode just for the app, on all view controllers in the app? I have my dark colors selected in `Assets.xcassets`

I understand that I can use `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` but this only changes the one viewController. I want it to switch the entire app.

Comment: You could also have a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13/56546554

Comment: When I do `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` just the one viewController changes. Also, the TabBar doesn't change. When I use `window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` i get this error "Use of unresolved identifier 'window'"

Comment: You have to put this line of code inside the ```willConnectTo``` method inside of your ```SceneDelegate``` file.

Comment: @Henhen1227 Happy to help! (You could also upvote my comment ;-))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set it on your app's window (it is also a view):

```
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Edit:
Add to SceneDelegate file in the willConnectTo func

For example:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```