# "User Interface Style" key in iOS Framework plist not working

Tags: xcode

When I add "User Interface Style" = "Light" in info.plist of iOS Framework, it does not get applied to the app in which that Framework is embedded.

Comment: This post very clear for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13

Comment: The link you have provided is for iOS App. I need it for iOS Framework specifically.

Answer (score 1):

To control an interface style[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUi9H.png) for an entire app, you simply set UIUserInterfaceStyle (Appearance) key[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4U47.png) in your Info.plist file.

You can assign it to either Light or Dark value to force a light and dark user interface style.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

or

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Dark</string>
```

[image]
**Full Article:** *https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-disable-dark-mode-in-ios/#disable-dark-mode-for-an-entire-app*