# Why is my app so different on my device vs. the simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

This what my app looks like running on the simulator (iPhone 8 Plus):

[image]

And this what it looks like running on my device (iPhone 7 Plus):

[image]

Why does it look like so much is missing from the app when I run it on my device? Also, a lot of the buttons/actions do not work. My data is sourced from Firestore and I am using Firebase for my app. The iOS Deployment Target is 14.4, which is accurate for my phone. I'm wondering if this could have something to do with my "Copy Bundle Resources" as this has caused me some issues in the past.

[image]

Any help/guidance on how I can troubleshoot this is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your device is in dark mode. The text is probably white when in dark mode, which makes the text match the background, making it look missing.

Comment: change your cell background color to [systemBackground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173140-systembackground)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, You haven't provided the support for the Dark mode. To fix this issue, Either you have to give support for dark mode or disable dark mode by adding the below key in the info.plist file. It will fix your issue.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

It Looks like your device is in dark mode. Please do changes in UI to support dark mode or you can use your app by disabling dark mode by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)

Answer (score 1):

Your device is in the dark theme whereas your simulator is in light theme,
You can assign it to work on a light theme by toggling the appearance as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Thank you everyone for the answers. I did indeed have to disable dark mode. It looks like the key has changed to the following, as per this link: [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)

```
<key> Appearance</key>
<string>Light</string>
```