# iOS, Swift Application is always running in Dark Mode

Tags: ios, darkmode

So I just want my app to always run in dark mode. Even if the device appearance in in Light I still want the app to run in dark mode. Is this possible?

Comment: Just design your app with a dark mode UI and don't use the dark mode aware UIColor presets.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, It's possible, You must Add "Appearance" key to "Dark" in Info.plist such as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to `Dark` in your Info.plist as explained in [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)