# SwiftUI alert and confirmation dialog preferredColorScheme

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've noticed when setting the `preferredColorScheme` in my SwiftUI app the `.alert` and `.confirmationDialog` modifiers don't use the `colorScheme`. Also the launch screen doesn't use the `colorScheme` either. It seems to be using system defaults, is this normal behaviour?

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .preferredColorScheme(.light)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: swiftui colorscheme]

I was also unable to get better results using `UIKit`'s `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`. The launch screen is still using system defaults, unsure how to solve that in `SwiftUI` without a launch screen. Also the code becomes pretty ugly and much more extensive.

```swift
guard let scene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
scene.keyWindow?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light // .light .dark .unspecified
```

[image: UIKit UserInterfaceStyle]

Comment: For launch screen use UILaunchScreen corresponding property values (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uilaunchscreen)

Comment: @Asperi my SwiftUI app doesn’t contain any UILaunchScreen. Also that doesn’t really answer the issue for alert or confirmation dialogs.

Comment: The preferredColorScheme by documentation is applied for current presentation. Alerts/dialogs has different presentation. Probably it is a bug, probably not. "doesn’t contain any UILaunchScreen" - so system one is used (note: launch screen is created and shown *before* your content view with modifier even created).

Comment: @Asperi I think I'm just going to use `UIKit` for this instead of `preferredColorScheme`.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a *pure* SwiftUI way, but I found a simple solution. Use `UIKit`, then handle the changes in SwiftUI. I just needed to use `.overrideUserInterfaceStyle`. As for the `Launch Screen` in SwiftUI, add a `Background color` key to the dictionary. Then add a `Color set`from your assets and set the `Background color` key value to the name of the asset created as a `String`.

```swift
let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
guard let scene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return nil }
scene.keyWindow?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light //.dark, .light, .unspecified
```

[image: Launch Screen]

[image: Color Set]

Comment: @Cole Thanks for posting this code. I had the same issue with confirmationDialog() and dark mode.  Your code solved my problem.

Comment: have no effect for me.