# There is no line occurrence in the info plist file Xcode

Tags: xcode

I want to disable the dark mode in the application. For this you need to go to the info `plist` file and then to the appearance tab, but my info `plist` file is almost empty. In other applications, it has many more lines, but here there are only 2.

Does anyone know how to find the appearance tab? I tried deleting it and putting in a new file from another app, but that caused errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to opt-out of dark mode on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537855/is-it-possible-to-opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-13)