# How to provide CGColor dynamically when switching dark/light mode?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode

I've set up a dynamic `UIColor`s for OS13 in my Swift app to handle dark mode.

For example:

```swift
static var background: UIColor {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        return UIColor { (traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
            if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                return UIColor(hex: "2b2d42")
            } else {
                return UIColor(hex: "FFFFFF")
            }
        }
    } else {
        return UIColor(hex: "FFFFFF")
    }
}
```

And wherever in code `CGColor` is used instead of `UIColor` I was planning to call `traitCollectionDidChange` of that particular `UIView` like this for example:

```swift
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    layer.fillColor = color.cgColor
}
```

It works but what I noticed is, that after changing the mode in settings if I use bottom swipe gesture to switch back to my app, then I can see all the `UIColor`s already updated on the incoming screen, but the `CGColor`s get updated only when app actually comes to foreground and `traitCollectionDidChange` is called.

[image]

Is there a better approach to this, so that the `CGColor`s also get updated immediately?

Comment: May be this will be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487679/how-do-i-easily-support-light-and-dark-mode-with-a-custom-color-used-in-my-app

Answer (score 1):

go to Xcode > Assets.xcassets > new Color Set > set color for Light and Dark Appearance

now set this color in view background color

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "ColorForCameraScreen")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! You can use [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to inline your image.

Comment: I have a problem with the color of the logo, the background gets set correctly since it uses `UIColor` with dynamic provider, the problem is with logo where color is set with `CGColor` not `UIColor`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes, this is your only choice.

`CGColor` is a `CoreGraphics` primitive, a plain static C struct which doesn't  benefit from new `UIColor` dynamism capabilities.

However, in recent versions of iOS (I am testing on 15.0), your `CGColors` should be updated correctly in the App Switcher.

You can find more details in [this article by jessesquires](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/03/23/implementing-dark-mode-with-cgcolor/) and in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63380259/2087108).

I hope this (late) answer helps shed some light on this.